# plotting ROOT LOCUS for parametric zero

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I would like to analize an LTI closed loop system using Root Locus diagram.

This is the system:

[image: This is the system:]

The MATLAB function **rlocus** plots the closed loop poles for a varying gain parameter **K**.
I would like to plot the closed loop poles for varying parameter **a**, which appears as a zero of the system **G**.

I know it is possilbe to manipulate the algebric expression describing the closed loop poles so it would match the common expression **1+aG*=0** for a different well defined system **G***,

I would like to do it directly using MATLAB function.

thanks

Comment: What if you limit the **K** gain as 1 and input the transfer function into a loop with `rlocus(num, den, K)`

Comment: @mehmet - Close, but you'd need to create a `tf` object using `num` and `den`, then use `rlocus` via `rlocus(T, K);`.

Comment: @mehmet - Make a new answer.  Don't edit my answer if you want to communicate.

Comment: @rayryeng oh sorry, I didn' t want to be disrespectful to your answer making a new. If you receive my edit, not important the rest..

Comment: @mehmet - You didn't :) Thank you for communicating to me though.  I saw your edit nonetheless!  Very interesting, and thanks for the timing benchmark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rlocus` assumes that the closed-loop control system has unit feedback, and that there is a proportional controller that you use to vary the gain to plot your poles and zeroes.  If you want to vary the zero and plot the locations of the closed-loop poles, you can loop through a specified range... say... between -2 and 2 in steps of 0.01, compute the closed-loop transfer function and extract the poles from the result.  If you recall from control theory, the transfer function of a closed-loop system is:

[image]

`G(s)` would be the transfer function in the forward loop, which is `G(s)` in your picture, and `H(s)` would be the transfer function of the feedback, which is 1 in your picture.  Therefore, your closed-loop TF is:

```
T(s) = G / (1 + G)
```

For each value of `a`, simply create a transfer function via [`zpk`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/zpk.html) using your poles and zeroes defined in `G(s)`, then compute `G / (1 + G)`, then extract out the poles from this new transfer function.  Once you extract these poles with [`zpkdata`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/zpkdata.html), plot the real and imaginary components of the poles on a graph.  Make sure you spawn a new figure, and use `hold on` to allow for plotting multiple points with the `for` loop iterations.  Therefore, your code may look something like this:

```
figure;
hold on;
for a = -2 : 0.01 : 2
    G = zpk([-a -1], [0 0 0], 1);
    T = G / (1 + G);
    [Z,P,K] = zpkdata(T);
    plot(real(P{:}), imag(P{:})', 'ro');
end
grid;
```

It should be noted that `Z` and `P` are cell arrays, so using `{:}` unrolls the cell array data so that they becomes numeric arrays.  The above code will do what I just talked about and it will plot the closed-loop poles of your transfer function with red circles.

This is what I get:

[image]

---

Alternatively, you can do what @mehmet suggests and you can replace the `zpkdata` call with a `rlocus` call, but provide an output variable to this statement so you can get the closed-loop system poles when `K=1`.  After, you can plot these results on your graph.  If you do this, it seems to run faster.  Something like:

```
figure;
hold on;
for a = -2 : 0.01 : 2
    G = zpk([-a -1], [0 0 0], 1);
    [R,K] = rlocus(G, 1);
    plot(real(R), imag(R), 'ro');
end
grid;
```

When you call `rlocus` this way, `R` would contain the closed-loop system poles when `K=1` using the `G(s)` specified in your question.  `K` would also just be 1 as you specified only one gain. You should get the same results as the first method above.

Comment: @Day_Dreamer my pleasure! This is the first time I've answered a controls related question... And it's one of my areas of expertise. I'd answer more of them, but I don't see many here... Probably because it's too specialized. Good luck!